# encrypt .env variables to be used in docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose, .env, docker-secrets

I'm following a [tutorial to set up elasticsearch with docker-compose](https://www.elastic.co/blog/getting-started-with-the-elastic-stack-and-docker-compose).  The tutorial has a `.env` file with something like:

```
ELASTIC_USER=changeme
ELASTIC_PASS=changeme
```

Does `docker-compose` have a way to encrypt the value of variables that have been loaded from a `.env` file?  I've seen some SO questions and blogs from 10 years ago saying that this is not possible, or that you would need to use `docker swarm` to leverage the ability to encrypt values loaded from a `.env` file.

It is now the year 2023, about 10 years since those last posts.  Is there a modern practice for encrypting secrets to be used in `docker-compose`?

---

NOTE: elasticsearch itself does have keystores for this purpose, but I've been running into technical complications with them when used in containerized environment.  I am continuing to resolve these complications, but wanted to see if `docker-compose` offers me any alternatives.